# I can ping IPs, but can't ping any domain

Tags: centos, ping, domain-name-system

I have a CentOS 6 x86 server. If I ping 8.8.8.8 and my server gateway, there's no problem. If I ping google.com, yahoo.com, etc, it returns "ping: unknown host google.com".

When I saw this problem, first thing I go to check is the /etc/resolv.conf file, but this file seems no problem. Where else should I check?

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: The second nameserver should probably be 4.4.4.4?

Comment: Nop, 4.4.4.4 is not working anymore.

Comment: @DrI: Good to know. It is a long time ago I had to use them the last time.

Answer (score 3):

Few things you can try

Look at

```
/etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Look for hosts: and see if it has dns listed

Then try to query google.com from their nameservers.. maybe output dns requests are failing

```
nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8
```

If that fails.. then

```
telnet 8.8.8.8 53
```

If you get a connection refused.. your ISP might be blocking your dns requests and you have to use their resolvers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you maybe have a firewall in between which is blocking DNS traffic? You can try to make a lookup with dig and see if it works or not:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 www.google.com
```

If this does not work then it is probably a device (firewall) in between which is blocking your DNS traffic.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you don't have internet access at all, don't you?

If this is the case, have a look at your routing table using command `route`.

If you don't see a line like this one:

```
default 8.8.8.4 0.0.0.0
```

you probably have a gateway problem, check your network settings.

Comment: He sais that he can ping 8.8.8.8 so he has internet access for sure.

Comment: My bad, I didn't noticed that this ip was public google dns. I thought this was the ip for his router. They have a troubleshooting page here, maybe it will help. [link](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html#troubleshooting)